# combining data within columns using SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

| type1 | value1 | type2 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | B | 2 |
| B | 2 | C | 3 |
| C | 3 | D | 4 |

In this data, A   1   is coupled to D    4, via B 2 and C3. So the result I would like to get is:

```
|  A    |   1    |   D   |   4    |
```

How can I do that with SQL?

I have no clue yet on how to achieve this

Comment: That is a graph structure. See [sql-graph-architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture)

Comment: looks feasible with a recursive query, which dbms are you currently using?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing transitivity using SQL varies by database and doesn't fit a single standard for the SQL language.

In MySQL, you could do the following query and take the last row, assuming your existing table is named 'links'.

```
WITH RECURSIVE reachable AS (
    SELECT type1 as type, value1 as value, 1 as level FROM links
    WHERE type1='A' and value1='1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l.type2, l.value2, r.level+1
    FROM reachable r, links l
    WHERE l.type1=r.type2 and l.value1=r.value2
)
```

I feel it necessary to state some caveats.  Your data could conceivably have loops, such as `{C,3,B,2}`, or branches, such as `{C,3,E,5}`.  The former would not be handled appropriately, and the latter could give multiple valid results.  If you need to support loops, you'll need to makes some adjustments.  If you have multiple valid results, you need to determine if a tie-breaking condition is warranted.

Comment: Thx! I am using Teradata. Will try to apply this.